# Remove empty fields in json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have this json file and I have to remove some null fields. I have posted my json file and also the json file that I am expecting. Can you help me what codes should I write for this to happen?

Here is my json file:

```
{
 "selection1": [
  {
   "name": "Radisson Blu Azuri Resort & Spa",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/radisson-blu-azuri-resort-hotel-deals.html",
   "reviews": [
{
     "name": "4",
     "date": "October 09, 2015",
     "review": "The personal was friendly , helpful n professional and put you at ease."
    },
    {
     "name": "3",
     "date": "July 20, 2015",
     "review": "Everyone really enjoy each moment we had there. The staffs are all very friendly and professionals."
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Manta Cove by Horizon Holidays",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/manta-cove-by-horizon-holidays.html"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sous Le Badamier",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/sous-le-badamier.html"
  },
  {
   "name": "Honeymoon Special at Lagoon Attitude",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/honeymoon-special-at-lagoon-attitude.html",
   "reviews": [
    {
     "name": "3",
     "date": "January 20, 2020",
     "review": "Lagoon Attitude has been my best hotel stay ever in Mauritius. The eco friendly concept is one of a kind, esp. with the water fountains. My friends and I were warmly welcomed upon arrival. The staff were amazingly friendly, very professional and hospitable."
    },
{
     "name": "134",
     "date": "June 12, 2019",
     "review": "Had an amazing stay for 2 nights.\nThe cleanliness of the room is faultless"
    },
    {
     "name": "132",
     "date": "April 11, 2019",
     "review": "A highly recommendable hotel. Value for money and thanks to Marideal.\nThe room provided to us was very clean, and well maintained, we got a room in the 1800`s range, personal swimming pool along being cleaned everyday."
    },
    {
     "name": "131",
     "date": "January 24, 2019",
     "review": "Super week-end en famille. Merci à toute l'équipe du Radisson pour votre accueil, votre gentilesse et votre écoute."
    },
    {
     "name": "2",
     "date": "January 06, 2020",
     "review": "Our second visit to the hotel. Fantastic experience with the new Otentik concept. The personnel is the most welcoming and kind to us, namely Mr Kevin and Mr Jevissen, as well as Ms Veronique, to name a few."
    } 
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

What should I do to remove the empty fields and make my json file looks like:

```
{
 "selection1": [
  {
   "name": "Radisson Blu Azuri Resort & Spa",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/radisson-blu-azuri-resort-hotel-deals.html",
   "reviews": [
{
     "name": "4",
     "date": "October 09, 2015",
     "review": "The personal was friendly , helpful n professional and put you at ease."
    },
    {
     "name": "3",
     "date": "July 20, 2015",
     "review": "Everyone really enjoy each moment we had there. The staffs are all very friendly and professionals."
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Honeymoon Special at Lagoon Attitude",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/honeymoon-special-at-lagoon-attitude.html",
   "reviews": [
    {
     "name": "3",
     "date": "January 20, 2020",
     "review": "Lagoon Attitude has been my best hotel stay ever in Mauritius. The eco friendly concept is one of a kind, esp. with the water fountains. My friends and I were warmly welcomed upon arrival. The staff were amazingly friendly, very professional and hospitable."
    },
{
     "name": "134",
     "date": "June 12, 2019",
     "review": "Had an amazing stay for 2 nights.\nThe cleanliness of the room is faultless"
    },
    {
     "name": "132",
     "date": "April 11, 2019",
     "review": "A highly recommendable hotel. Value for money and thanks to Marideal.\nThe room provided to us was very clean, and well maintained, we got a room in the 1800`s range, personal swimming pool along being cleaned everyday."
    },
    {
     "name": "131",
     "date": "January 24, 2019",
     "review": "Super week-end en famille. Merci à toute l'équipe du Radisson pour votre accueil, votre gentilesse et votre écoute."
    },
    {
     "name": "2",
     "date": "January 06, 2020",
     "review": "Our second visit to the hotel. Fantastic experience with the new Otentik concept. The personnel is the most welcoming and kind to us, namely Mr Kevin and Mr Jevissen, as well as Ms Veronique, to name a few."
    } 
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Can someone explain to me on how to remove the empty fields so that my json file is ready to do preprocessing of 'review' for each loop?

Comment: read JSON file to memory to have dictionary, remove empty elements from dictionary, save dictionary back to JSON file

Comment: I am having difficulties to do this, can you help me?

Comment: use `for`-loop with reviews and copy to other list elements which you want to keep - and later assign it in place of old list

Comment: is it possible for you to write it in the answer box for me please?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for`-loop to iterate `data["selection1"]` and copy to new dictionary only elements which have `reviews`

```
import json

# read from file
#with open('input.json') as f:
#    data = json.load(f)

data = {
 "selection1": [
  {
   "name": "Radisson Blu Azuri Resort & Spa",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/radisson-blu-azuri-resort-hotel-deals.html",
   "reviews": [
{
     "name": "4",
     "date": "October 09, 2015",
     "review": "The personal was friendly , helpful n professional and put you at ease."
    },
    {
     "name": "3",
     "date": "July 20, 2015",
     "review": "Everyone really enjoy each moment we had there. The staffs are all very friendly and professionals."
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Manta Cove by Horizon Holidays",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/manta-cove-by-horizon-holidays.html"
  },
  {
   "name": "Sous Le Badamier",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/sous-le-badamier.html"
  },
  {
   "name": "Honeymoon Special at Lagoon Attitude",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/honeymoon-special-at-lagoon-attitude.html",
   "reviews": [
    {
     "name": "3",
     "date": "January 20, 2020",
     "review": "Lagoon Attitude has been my best hotel stay ever in Mauritius. The eco friendly concept is one of a kind, esp. with the water fountains. My friends and I were warmly welcomed upon arrival. The staff were amazingly friendly, very professional and hospitable."
    },
    {
     "name": "134",
     "date": "June 12, 2019",
     "review": "Had an amazing stay for 2 nights.\nThe cleanliness of the room is faultless"
    },
    {
     "name": "132",
     "date": "April 11, 2019",
     "review": "A highly recommendable hotel. Value for money and thanks to Marideal.\nThe room provided to us was very clean, and well maintained, we got a room in the 1800`s range, personal swimming pool along being cleaned everyday."
    },
    {
     "name": "131",
     "date": "January 24, 2019",
     "review": "Super week-end en famille. Merci à toute l'équipe du Radisson pour votre accueil, votre gentilesse et votre écoute."
    },
    {
     "name": "2",
     "date": "January 06, 2020",
     "review": "Our second visit to the hotel. Fantastic experience with the new Otentik concept. The personnel is the most welcoming and kind to us, namely Mr Kevin and Mr Jevissen, as well as Ms Veronique, to name a few."
    } 
   ]
  }
 ]
}

# dictionary for element which you want to keep
new_data = {'selection1': []}

# copy item from old data to new data if it has 'reviews'
for item in data['selection1']:
    if 'reviews' in item:
        new_data['selection1'].append(item)
        #print(item['reviews'])
        #print('--')

# save in file
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(new_data, f)
```